# Asynchronous LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I was looking for an async `.Where()` but could not find one so after some research I've created one.

```
public static class LinqExtension
{
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> WhereAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task<bool>> @delegate)
    {
        var tasks = source.Select(async t => new
        {
            Predicate = await @delegate(t).ConfigureAwait(false),
            Value = t
        }).ToList();

        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

        IEnumerable<T> typeList = results.Where(pred => pred.Predicate).Select(val => val.Value);
        return typeList;
    }
}
```

When I try to use it i get runtime error

> Cannot convert implicit type bool to Task and yes it's correct

This is how I've tried

```
var q = await context.StockHistories.WhereAsync(x => x.ProductId == productId);
```

I've tried

```
context.StockHistories.WhereAsync(Task.Run(() => { x => x.ProductId == productId; }));
```

but getting

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

Can please someone provide a solution and explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Making the lambda expression async is not going to make the method async because it's just translating that into SQL.  The async methods are just the ones that will run the query like `ToListAsync` or `FirstOrDefaultAsync`.

Comment: This looks like something from Reactive Extensions and not LINQ.

Comment: @Euphoric How would you use Reactive Extensions with EF?

Comment: @juharr This is not using EF. If he is creating his own Where method, the EF will load all data into memory and then run the Where on CPU. It won't be part of SQL query.

Comment: Also, he is using IEnumerable, not IQueryable. Eg. entity-framework tag is wrong.

Comment: If you are working with entity framework you should use `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` or your queries won't be processed by the server.

Comment: @Euphoric But he's calling it on a `context` which indicates EF and there's not much point to making Linq-to-Objects asynchronous.  But if you did you wouldn't do it to the lazy evaluated methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The async methods for EF are the ones that execute the query.  So what you actually want is

```
var q = await context.StockHistories.Where(x => x.ProductId == productId).ToListAsync();
```

Basically there isn't an asynchronous `Where` method because it doesn't make sense to have one because it's just used to generate the actual SQL that will be executed on the DB.  The query isn't actually run until you iterate the results, and all the methods that do that have an asynchronous version.

Comment: I think the OP doesn't have a `Func` that can accept a `StockHistory` and produce a `bool` synchronously. They could block using `Result` in the `Where` delegate, but that's not great performancewise

Comment: Ah, nvm. Just noticed this is EF; so the delegate is never actually evaluated.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Yeah, the lambda passed to the `Where` is translated into SQL.